# angular single page app, videoJS ready function only fires on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video.js

Trying to get videoJS to work in an angular directive using ng-view template. Angular routing and template injection is all working fine.

html code:

```
<div ng-view>
</div>
```

template code:

```
<div ng-controller="VideoCntrl">
    <div class="row offset2" >
        <video id='myVideo' videodir controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin" >
            <source src="{{video.videoURL}}"  type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

directive code

```
    app.directive('videodir',function(){
        var linkFn;

        linkFn = function (scope, element, attrs){
               videojs("myVideo",{"techOrder": ["html5","flash"]},function(){
                    this.src({type: "video/mp4", src: scope.video.videoURL});
                    console.log(scope.video.videoURL);
                });
                console.log('linkfn');
            };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linkFn
    }
});
```

The videojs ready function in the directive videodir ONLY fires the first time the page is hit or if I do a page reload. The first time I hit my page I see in console log the url of my video from scope.video.videoURL and the DOM is using videoJS. If I click on navigation links to load a different template and then come back, videojs ready function doesn't fire (i.e. I don't see my videoURL in the console log and the DOM is not changed by videoJS. I do see 'linkFn' in the console each time the template code is loaded. I assume in the directive where I am doing console.log('linkFn') there is some initialization code I can call on the videojs("myVideo") object so that it manipulates the DOM properly but I can't figure out what that might be.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a live sample on a service such as jsbin.com. It is difficult to understand exactly what you mean by "click on navigation links to load a different template and then come back". If you make that demo, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on that. Basically I mean that navigating to a page which results in angular replacing the contents of the div ng-view with a different template and then coming back to this page so angular replaces the template in ng-view with the <div ng-controller ...> and runs the videodir directive results in the videojs ready function not executing. I appreciate the suggestion and your offer. Thanks

Comment: You might find my code helpful. I've built a more IOS friendly version where the player just starts as an image. Then whenever you load up a new page or template you just call my function callMovies(); Here's the page with the zip folder.

Comment: Sorry here's the link = http://www.andy-howard.com/recreate-bbc-iplayer/index.html

Comment: I feel like this is related question, except that I use backbone.js. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792794/video-js-with-backbone-js-skin-is-not-applied

Answer (score 8):

When you use videoJs with angular in a single page app, you need to destroy the videojs player manually when your scope is destroyed (when you navigate away from the state the player was created in), and reload it when you create it again.

The ready state doesn't fire again because when you navigate back, the videojs player is technically already created, just your $scope has no way to keep track of it.

Rather than defining the player source in the DOM, create the videojs object dynamically

Useful links

(dynamically create a player)

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md#alternative-setup-for-dynamically-loaded-html

(Disposing a player in angular directives)

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/808

DOM

```
<video id='myVideo' videodir controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin" ></video>
```

Controller

```
var setupOpt = {
    'controls' : false,
    'autoplay' : false,
    'preload' : 'auto',
    // 'poster' : asset.thumbnail,
    'width' : 'auto',
    'height': 'auto'
};

//inject $sce to use any url, or fetch url from http request
var vidSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("example.mp4"); 

//create video js player dynamically
videojs( 'myVideo', setupOpt, function(){
   $scope.vid = videojs( 'myVideo' ).src([ {type: "video/mp4", src: vidSrc} ]);
});

//destroy video when $scope is destroyed
$scope.$on( '$destroy', function() {
    console.log( 'destroying video player' );
    $scope.vid.dispose();
});
```

Comment: What if I put the <video> tag outside of ng-view, and stored the player in a $rootScope variable that can be accessed throughout the app regardless of the routes hit?  That way the player doesn't need to be destroyed and I can use it on subsequent views?

The problem I'm having with this approach though, is that when I update the player source, the duration does not get updated in the player.

Answer (score 2):

Do you see any other errors in console?
The issue might be related to the fact, that the player was not properly disposed.

See, for example, these discussions:

- https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/189
- http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1284-firefox-error-with-elvjs_getproperty

I am not an angular expert, but when you go back and forth between views, the player won't be disposed automatically.