# Video.js with Backbone.js - skin is not applied

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, video.js

I use videojs 4 with backbonejs, and in some cases the player is rendered, but default skin in is not applied. Instead I see some "default" controls [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkXuh.png)

Any particular order of loading videojs components is required? It loads correctly, when I open the page, but if I navigate to it from the other view -- not.

[image: player]

Answer (score 0):

I realized this happens if there is an internal JS error during the player initialisation. Seems like the process does not complete in this case, and skin is not applied. I solved the issue by controlling how my player is disposed.

This discussion helped https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/189