# videojs doesn't load when change state with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, video.js

I am working on a project with videojs that must work on Firefox and IE 11, and is built with a angular-ui-router. One of the states has a video player, and on the first time loading, videojs properly generates the content. However, if you navigate away from that state and come back, videojs content isn't generated and the default html5 video element is displayed. Is there a way to deal with this problem? In addition, (more often in IE 11), videojs will sometimes randomly fail to generate the content on the first page load. I can't figure out if the problems are related, or what is even causing the problem because there are no errors in the console log.

I'm not sure what code will even be relevant to post. Here is the html for the video:

```
<video controls preload data-setup="{}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered full-video"  poster="img/CollaborationPoster.png">
        <source ng-repeat="src in video.srcs"  ng-src="{{src.url | trustUrl}}" type="{{src.mimeType}}"/>
</video>
```

In addition I have:

```
window.VIDEOJS_NO_DYNAMIC_STYLE = true;
```

At the start of my app. However, the problem still exists if I get rid of this.

Feel free to ask for any other code that could help diagnose the problem

(NOTE: I am also open to suggestions on using a different framework/etc for the video component. videojs has been very frustrating overall)

EDIT: In case it's relevant, 'full-video' is the only custom class for the video and its styling is:

```
.full-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and I find a way to solve it.

Add this code in your controller may help you.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    video.dispose();
});
```

Video is the player object created by videojs() function.

Can look at this discussion for more infomation.

[angular single page app, videoJS ready function only fires on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751314/angular-single-page-app-videojs-ready-function-only-fires-on-page-load/29638431#29638431)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using some form of routing? Perhaps you need to reload the controller/directive/component.

Comment: Hey Mike, I can elaborate more: I am using an angular-ui-router which maps states to components. I am pretty certain that by default these components are reloaded when I change states, which means all of that should be reloaded as well

Comment: hmm, you could try an explicit {reload: true} using the 3rd param in state.go/trasition, ui-sref-opts, or possibly even in the route definition.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're saying. But I think the eventual goal was to not have the page reload when the state changes back (aka to preserve the information/data that is loaded). This would prevent performance issues. Given that, I'll probably have to manually load videojs somehow.